# Error TF31002 When Trying to Connect SSDT 2010 TO VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

Trying to connect my Visual Studio Team Services server in SQL Data Tools 2010, but getting the following error, i have correctly installed the Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 - ISO

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio online currently only works with VS2013 and above. It's not support for SSDT2010. You may need to use SSDT in VS2013 and try again.

> **SSDT is available in VS 2013, it's integrated into the box** so we do
>   not have a stand alone install. If you install VS 2013, you will see
>   the Database Projects, SQL Server Object Explorer, and other tools
>   that were available in VS 2010 & VS 2012. I have verified that the
>   Database Projects in VS2013 will work with VS Online source control,
>   however if you are using the online build process, we are not built
>   into the online build support yet.
>
> Posted by Jill [MSFT] on 1/13/2014 at 2:36 PM

More detail info please refer this link: [SSDT with VIsual Studio Online](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/813509/ssdt-with-visual-studio-online)